# How to change the color of Notification Bar

Tags: android

When the user is running my application, I want to set the color of the Notification bar to the color used in my app, it will look good & will enhance the branding of my app.

As different versions of android are having different color of Notification bar like in before 2.2 it was light gray, then it becomes a little darker in the further releases to black.

I want to set a different color to the notification bar that can be viewed on all android versions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only allowed after KitKat.

I've found this project that might help you.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set the color of the Notification bar to the color used in my app,

AFAIK You Cannot

Try a full screen theme for your application or activity with notification bar hidden. Show anything you want to show at top to match to your branding.

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy to change the Notification bar colour. AFAIK, to change the notification bar you need a rooted phone and an Xposed framework with Gravity Box! You can hide it though, if you want, full screen(No Action Bar), You can do as above in the manifest file, or in the class file add-

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

If you want just No Notification Bar but also dont want the notification bar use-

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```